# Two way sync between git and svn

Tags: git, svn, subgit

Is there any migration tool to migrate svn to git and maintain both repository in sync automatically.

I have used subgit tool for svn to git migration and does two way sync successfully.

Apparently subgit is not suitable for TFS server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subgit installation on TFS Maintained Git repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479733/subgit-installation-on-tfs-maintained-git-repo)

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge, I think the relationship between his two questions may be reversed.  I get the impression that in the intervening hour he may have given up on the "How" question to which you've linked in favor of this "Recommend Alternatives" question.